# Regular expression group word and sentence

Tags: regex, text-editor, atom-editor

I would like to make a regular expression that does the following:

1. Gets the whole line of a text file
2. Gets the first word of that line
3. Outputs into an input

Currently I can do each of those separately but as one call it is getting hairy:

Whole Line

```
^\b(.*)\b
```

First Word

```
^\b(\w*)\b
```

Replace for Input

```
<div class="field"><label><input class="input-checkbox" id="Foo$1" name="Foo" type="checkbox" value="$1" /> <span>$1</span> </label></div>
```

I would like to use $1 and $2 to separate between the full line for the text display and the first word for the value and ID. Any thoughts?  I really like regular expressions for their usefulness and speed as long as I don't hit a knowledge road block like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the entire match:

```
Search: ^(\w+).*
Replace: First word is $1, whole line is $&
```

In your case, the replacment term would be:

```
<div class="field"><label><input class="input-checkbox" id="Foo$1" name="Foo" type="checkbox" value="$1" /> <span>$0</span> </label></div>
```

The entire match in Atom is coded as `$&`.

Most other tools/languages use group zero `$0` for the entire match.

Comment: I tried that and figured `$0` wasn't a thing but since you suggested it I did a little more digging. I didn't state that I was using the Atom text editor so I looked up `$0` for atom and they don't use it, they instead use `$&` so it all works now. Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelF cool. I've edited the answer to incorporate your discovery - I learned something too!